# AS3 MVC Event Listener [Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, event-listener

I am using the `MVC` pattern as described by

http://www.swinburne.edu.au/design/tutorials/P-flash/T-The-Model-View-Controller-Design-Pattern-in-Actionscript-3/ID-144/

However for my project I am using a view with child sprites like this in `ascii` art:

```
[[menu][ Content ]]
```

the container for content is called `displayPanelContent`

The content sprite uses a listener like below to use the update function:

```
super.getModel().addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, this.update, false, 0, true);
```

however when I try and delete the content sprite using

```
while (displayPanelContent.numChildren > 1) {
displayPanelContent.removeChildAt(1);
}
```

I get an error message:

> [Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a
>   property or method of a null object reference.

If I remove the listener it deletes fine but the error message is so vague I can't discern the error.

I'm trying to avoid posting the code because the whole pattern and application is really verbose.

Comment: Clarify what line causes the error, please.

Comment: I fixed it, It was a case of initialising a class with a global value which always defaulted to null as the constructor hadn't been called yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not vague at all.

It clearly states that you are operating on an object reference that doesn't reference an object, but `null`.

So whatever line causes the error includes a reference that's referencing `null`.

Comment: the problem is I can't discern which one is null in my ide.